Solving an Ordinary Differential Equation IVP using only $v=y/x$ instead of homogeneous ODE formula
The question is $$xy\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2+y^2$$
Here are the official solutions: 
However, I have done it a different way. Dividing the initial euqation by $x^2$ and letting $v=y/x$ transforms it into $$\int \frac{v}{1-2v^2}dv=\int \frac{1}{x}dx$$
from which you integrate, raise everything to $e$ and get $$\left|1-2v^2\right|=e^{C}x^{-4}$$. Where $e^C$ ≠ $0$. Then getting rid of the absolute value $$1-2v^2= \pm e^{C}x^{-4} = Ax^{-4}$$ For all $A$ real excluding $0$ . From which you substitute back $y$ and $x$, use the IVP to find $A = -7$, and the answer is
$$x^2 -2y^2=-7/x^2$$
What did I do wrong?

$v=\frac{y}{x}\implies y=xv \implies y'=xv'+v.$ Therefore, dividing both sides of $xyy'=x^2+y^2$ by $x^2$ one gets $v(xv'+v)=1+v^2\implies vv'=\frac{1}{x}$. Can you identify your mistake?

yes oops i see thank you i solved it

Define a new function $u(t)$ by $u(x^2)=y(x)^2$. Then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}u(x^2)=2xu'(x^2)=2y(x)y'(x)
\\ \implies
x^2u'(x^2)=xyy'=x^2+y^2
\\ \implies
tu'(t)=t+u(t).
$$
This now is a nice linear DE, of Cauchy-Euler type if one wants to go there.
